# How to install Ubuntu on a Mac and keep OSX?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, mac, macosx, refit

Could anyone provide a concise step by step instruction on how to install Ubuntu 12.04 on a Mac OS X Lion?

I have read that Ubuntu corrupts the EFI file so I would like to hear from those who have successfully done it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### For 12.04:

I wrote an extensive tutorial [here](http://tech-devnet.blogspot.de/2012/05/running-ubuntu-1204-on-mac.html). It worked perfectly well for me and I didn't have any issues since doing exactly what I describe in my blog post a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: can I safely assume that using the **install along side mac** installs into the created partition?

Comment: It is considered to be safe and it worked for me. But it isn't too difficult to specify the empty partition manually, so if you'd rather like to be absolutely certain...

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Please, instead of including just the link, include the facts. I don't see any restriction in the link you pasted.