# Is it possible to install Ubuntu on my iMac OSX 10.8.5?

Tags: installation

it's possible to  install Ubuntu on my  iMac OSX 10.8.5....

Do You guys have any tutorial on  because I am a dummy... or somewhere where I can learn.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of: [How to install Ubuntu 12.04 on Mac OS X?](http://askubuntu.com/q/151371/107450) or see here: [How to install Ubuntu on MacBook using USB Stick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20USB%20Stick)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is very much possible, download ubuntu from the [Ubuntu Downloads Page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and then either [Create a bootable flash disk](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx) or [Burn it onto DVD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-mac-osx) and then restart your machine with the either the disc inside the machine or the flash disk attached to the usb port.

I beleive noboy is a dummy, but if you really are not getting it, [Click this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu) to see detailed information and procedures on the installation process.