# Can I install Ubuntu on a Mac? (NO Dual Boot just Ubuntu)

Tags: boot, grub2, mac

I have googled for quite a while now and haven't found the answer. My question is, can I install Ubuntu on a mac and leaving out the Mac OS. I just want it to boot ubuntu and nothing else. Maybe a strange question but I got that Mac Book Pro (2012) for cheap and I just cannot get into Mac OS and I'd rather just have Ubuntu on it using the whole disk.

I have read of problems with Mac booting into GRUB without rEFIt or similar.
Is it possible?

Regards
anni

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate [How to install Ubuntu on a Mac and keep OSX?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151371/how-to-install-ubuntu-12-04-on-mac-os-x)

There's also nice Wiki article by Ubuntu Community on the topic; https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleIntelInstallation

Jump over to **Single-Boot: Ubuntu Only** section.